# Using python compare two excel workbook with multiple worksheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I was trying to build a tool to compare 2 versions of excel and get the results in different excel.

We have two workbook with multiple worksheets one is lower version say 1 and another one is higher version say 2. All the values will be same only few values are changed based on the business in higher version of workbook

I tried and got the result for first worksheet alone but my code is not comparing the whole workbook with another. Please help me in python to compare 2 workbook with multiple worksheets to get differences in another excel.

Here is the code

```py
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

dfrb1 =  pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx')

dfrb2 =  pd.read_excel('File2.xlsx')

comparevalues = dfrb1.values == dfrb2.values

rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
   dfrb1.iloc[item[0],item[1]] = ' {} --> {} '.format(dfrb1.iloc[item[0],item[1]], dfrb2.iloc[item[0],item[1]])

  
 dfrb1.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: You should post the code you have tried and explain where it is not doing as you expect or what the output is and what you expect, etc.

Comment: Please show us what you have done. If you are able to compare the first worksheet the others should not be hard, all you would have to do is iterate through those sheets...

Comment: added my code please advise

Comment: Please help me on this